# Nested Array Value twig 3rd child element

Tags: arrays, for-loop, twig

I've tried a nested Loop in Opencart Twig Template  but I cant get the child values

```html
{% for category in couriers.couriers %}
    {% set children = category.service_types %}
    {% for service_t in children %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ service_t.service_id }}</td>
            <td>{{ category.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ service_t.service_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ service_t.display_name }}</td>][1]][1]
            <td>{{ service_t.form_required }}</td>
            <td>{{ service_t.min_delivery_days }}</td>
            <td>{{ service_t.max_delivery_days }}</td>
            
            {% for rate_br in service_t.rate_breakup %}
                <td>{{ rate_br.base_rate }}</td>
            {% endfor %}    
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}    
{% endfor %}
```

My data looks like this

[image]

Comment: You're getting any errors? You're getting the wrong output?

Comment: Also `rate_breakup ` is not an array it's an object. You can't iterate object properties in `twig` by default. Use the full notation e.g. `{{ service_t.rate_breakup.base_rate  }}`